# How do I remove these "autofocus" selection borders from the Windows 8.1/8 tile screen?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, debug

Good evening, everyone.

I've just recently started to notice some unintended-enabled borders around my Windows 8 machine. Here are some screenshots:

[image: fig. a]
[image: fig. b]
[image: fig. c]

In the above photos, you will notice that there are white and black borders around items. Unfortunately, I somehow enabled these (unintentionally), and wish to remove them. To clarify, I do not use keyboard navigation (arrow keys). It seems to be selecting the first item in most of the lists, as if it's ready for me to use the arrow keys to navigate. I have confirmed that in a new account I created, this issue does not occur, so it's obviously a problem with the end-user (myself).

If anyone has any suggestions on how to get rid of these obtrusive eyesores, please contribute.

To clarify further, these borders are these when the start menu is opened instantly. If I try to click somewhere else to remove the selection, while I hold the mouse down, the border is gone. However, when I release the mouse, it comes right back.

Comment: Press Win+U to open the Ease of Access Center, and click the **Make the computer easier to see** link. Then check if the **Make the focus rectangle thicker** option is enabled.

Comment: @and31415 That didn't fix it. It was not enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control Panel►System►Advanced System Settings:
[image]